# NSKeyedArchiver strange behaviour - saves expired objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

I have been wracking my brain over this one for a couple of days now. I have player data stored in individual .plist documents which are created by `NSKeyedArchiver`. Everything works fine for the most part; however, when I delete one of these .plist documents, load another one into the player object, and activate `NSKeyedArchiver` when the application enters the background via `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`, the `NSKeyedArchiver` *recreates* the deleted .plist file... with all its old data intact. If, on the other hand, I call the exact same archiving method from a segue or any other means, it doesn't do this. It recreates the file when called from `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` or `-applicationWillTerminate:...` which saves not only the current active object data, but the deleted one as well (which should have been overwritten given it's the same object) to two separate files.

I have tried `campsObject=nil;` (my player object) in the delete method, but apparently the data is still floating around in memory somewhere.

So, my question is, is there something special I should look out for when using `NSKeyedArchiver` from `-applicationDidEnterBackground` etc? Any ideas?

Character is created on character creation view controller and passed to next:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
//Initialize Camp object if not done already

if (!campsObject) {
    campsObject = [[Camp alloc]init];

}


//Set up documents directory based on character name input
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
if ([_characterName.text isEqual:@""]) {
    _characterName.text=@"Default Character";
}
NSString *savedFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",_characterName.text];
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:savedFileName];





//Check to see if file exists and unarchive it as campsObject
NSLog(@"Directory Checked for is %@",documentsDirectory);

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory]) {
    NSLog(@"File exists!");
    [self unArchiveObjects:self];
    //[self screenUpdateKatalam];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"File doesn't exist - will be created on exit, or backgrounding");
}

//Pass campsObject instance variable to next view controller
characterNameTextPassed=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_characterName.text];
NSLog(@"The character name passed will be %@",characterNameTextPassed);

ViewController *viewControllerInstance = [segue destinationViewController];
viewControllerInstance->campsObject=campsObject;
viewControllerInstance->documentsDirectory=documentsDirectory;
viewControllerInstance->characterNameTextPassed=characterNameTextPassed;
```

}

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if ([title isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: documentsDirectory error: nil];
    [self hideAndDisableAllButtons];
    campsObject=nil;
    characterNamesArray=nil;
    characterNameTextPassed=nil;
    documentsDirectory=nil;
    [self getCharacterNames:self];
    [self refreshEntryScreen];
}
```

Is the delete method (an alert that pops up asking if you are sure you want to delete)

```
- (IBAction)archiveCampsObject:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"File will be saved to %@",documentsDirectory);
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:campsObject toFile:documentsDirectory];
```

}

is the action that archives the object

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
[self archiveCampsObject:self];
NSLog(@"Background Saving Engaged!");
NSLog(@"Application going into the background");
```

}

is the background method

Comment: Show the code for what you're saving, when, and how you clean it up.

Comment: Nobody has had this problem or can see where I screwed up?